# How to drop movies(rows) that have less than 5 reviews - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on the [MovieLens](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/latest/) dataset using python/pandas which I am new to, so please bear with me. I was asked to keep only the movies with at least 5 reviews. It is supposed to count the occurrences of the movies' IDs and if there are less than 5 get rid of the rows with those movies' IDs. I have written the code below that changes nothing in the final ratings dataset and I don't know why.

```
ratings = pd.read_csv(ratings_path)
ratings_final = ratings.copy()

counts = dict()
for i in ratings.index:
    if ratings.loc[i, 'movieId'] not in counts:
        counts[ratings.loc[i, 'movieId']] = 1
    else:
        counts[ratings.loc[i, 'movieId']] = counts[ratings.loc[i, 'movieId']] + 1

for i in ratings.index:
    if counts[ratings.loc[i, 'movieId']] < 5:
        print("I'm here", ratings.loc[i, 'movieId'])
        ratings_final=ratings_final.drop([i])
```

However the following code works

```
ratings_final=ratings.drop([10, 12, 100833])
print(ratings_final)
```

Is there something wrong with my loop or is my thinking completely wrong? What should I do to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby movieId and then [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) the rating columns with count (number of occurrences) >=5. This will keep all rows that have >= 5 ratings from the ratings df.

```
ratings_final = ratings.groupby('movieId').filter(lambda x: x['rating'].count() >= 5)
```

Comment: Thanks. In this solution if I change the 'rating' column to 'movieId' it would be the same result right? Is there a particular reason you chose the 'rating' column?

Comment: You're welcome. In this case, yes, substituting 'rating' with 'movieId' gives the same result.  Using 'rating' was just more intuitive to me in this case based upon the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `groupby()`

```
rating_final = rating.groupby('movieId')['UserId'].nunique().reset_index(name="count")
rating_final = rating_final[rating_final["count"]>=5]
```

Here we group by `movieId`, so we basically aggregate. Based on that aggregation we need to perform an operation on the rows we want to put together. We want to check the movie that got more than  ratings. I assumed  ratings meant  different users, so we select the `userId` column and count the number of unique elements in it.
From then we just select the `movieId` that have at least 5 unique elements for userId.

Comment: This only returns a df with the movieid and count of ratings. IIUC the OP wants the ratings df, just without any movieid rows that have been rated < 5 times.